# MongoDB sort based on key/value of subdocument

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework, entity-attribute-value

So i have a dynamic collection called `data` with this kind of documents :

```
[
    {
        _id: 1,
        module_id: 5,
        dynamic_fields: [
            {key: "title", value: "title 1"},
            {key: "rate", value: 3},
            {key: "category", value: 12},
            {key: "body", value: "my content goes here 1"},
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: 2,
        module_id: 5,
        dynamic_fields: [
            {key: "title", value: "title 2"},
            {key: "rate", value: 5},
            {key: "category", value: 12},
            {key: "body", value: "my content goes here 2"},
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: 3,
        module_id: 5,
        dynamic_fields: [
            {key: "title", value: "title 3"},
            {key: "rate", value: 2},
            {key: "category", value: 12},
            {key: "body", value: "my content goes here 3"},
        ]
    }
]
```

### Question :

How can i get all documents with `dynamic_fields[key:category]=12` and sort it desc by `rate` value of it's subdocument.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's give it a try.

1. `mongodb-runner start` ([useful tool!](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-runner))
2. `mongo`
3. get some test data:

   ```
   db.test.insertMany([
    {
        _id: 1,
        module_id: 5,
        dynamic_fields: [
            {key: "title", value: "title 1"},
            {key: "rate", value: 3},
            {key: "category", value: 12},
            {key: "body", value: "my content goes here 1"},
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: 2,
        module_id: 5,
        dynamic_fields: [
            {key: "title", value: "title 2"},
            {key: "rate", value: 5},
            {key: "category", value: 12},
            {key: "body", value: "my content goes here 2"},
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: 3,
        module_id: 5,
        dynamic_fields: [
            {key: "title", value: "title 3"},
            {key: "rate", value: 2},
            {key: "category", value: 12},
            {key: "body", value: "my content goes here 3"},
        ]
    }
   ])
   ```

Now we have test data (note that I made `dynamic_fields` an array so the insert doesn't error).

We'll need to do this in stages in an aggregation.  If you want to see what is going on, you can run this starting with just the `$match` stage and then adding each stage to see how the pipeline transforms.

```
db.test.aggregate(
    { $match: { "dynamic_fields.key": "category", "dynamic_fields.value": 12} },
    // add a field that we can sort on.
    { $addFields: {
        "order": {
            $filter: {
              "input": "$dynamic_fields",
              "as": "d",
              "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$d.key", "rate" ] }
            }
        }
    }},
    // order is an array of one, so we unwind it so we have an object that 
    // we can sort on.
    { $unwind: "$order"},
    { $sort: {
        'order.value': 1 }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks Arthur. but i think it can not use index and it's very slow because of sort. is there a way to use index on `order` field ? @arthur

Comment: It’s not possible to use an index for the sort in this solution.